# LaTeX elsarticle style frontmatter

Tags: latex

I am experiencing a slight annoyance with LaTeX and Elsevier's `elsarticle` style.

[image]

I cannot get rid of the superscript `a` in front of the affiliation.

It is needed for multiple authors, so affiliations can be associated with different authors. It is unnecessary in case of a single author.

I could not find a way to remove it.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

This is my LaTeX code.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt,authoryear,nopreprintline]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Recursive Combinatorial Functions, Matrices,\\ and a Diagram Notation}

\author{Erich Neuwirth}%
\ead{erich.neuwirth@univie.ac.at}%
\affiliation{organisation={University of Vienna, Faculty of Computer Science}}%

\date{\today}
\end{frontmatter}

Some text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you planning to submit the article to Elsevier?

Comment: Possibly. But I am not in a rush.

Comment: In this case you shouldn't modify the layout. If the journal does not want the footnote mark, they will remove it.